# Removing selected items from the listbox

Tags: c#, python, listview, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple GUI program to manage priorities.

I have successfully managed to add items to the listbox, but now I need to remove them from the listbox, as well as from the list provided - because, correct me if I'm wrong - in C# when you create a ListView, you have crated the ListView itself (the object which is displayed on the screen), but you have to eventually crate a List<> to store the objects from the listview themselves. I recently learned that `END` parameter is used to append items to the **list**. Is this like making a List<> in C#?

So, now I want to remove selected items from the listbox (and from the list if I need to).

Here is where I am at:

```
# priorities.py
# GUI program to manage priorities

from tkinter import *

class GuiPart(Frame):

   def __init__(self, master):
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.master = master
       self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
       self.master.title("Priorities")
       self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):

       buttonAdd = Button(self.master, text = "Add", command = self.addItem).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W + E)

       buttonRemove = Button(self.master, text = "Remove", command = self.removeItem).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W + E)

       buttonEdit = Button(self.master, text = "Edit", command = self.editItem).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W + E)

       self.listBox = Listbox(self.master, width=30)
       self.listBox.grid(row=1, sticky=W + E, columnspan=3)

       self.textBox = Text(self.master, height=10, width=30)
       self.textBox.grid(row=3, columnspan=3, sticky=W + E + N + S)

   def get_priority_subject(self):
       return self.textBox.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

   def get_priority_order(self):
       return self.textBox.get('2.0', '2.0 lineend')

   def addItem(self):
       self.listBox.insert(END, self.get_priority_subject()+'  '+ self.get_priority_order())
       self.clearAll()

   def removeItem(self):
       pass

   def editItem(self):
       pass

   def clearAll(self):
       self.textBox.delete('1.0', END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    GuiPart(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: `Listbox`es' have a method called `delete()` to delete lines. You could use it to manually to change its contents. Alternatively, you could specify a `StringVar` via the `listvariable` option when you create the the `Listbox` and making changes to it which would automatically cause the associated `Listbox` to be updated according. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html) on `Listbox`es.

Comment: What should I specify as delete()'s parameter because I need to delete multiple selected items?

Comment: You'll have to call it multiple times with no second parameter. Might want to do it in reverse index order because deleting earlier ones will change the index of later ones (assuming you're using simple integer indexes). Personally, I suggest you use the `listvariable=` keyword and a `StringVar` because it would let you do the update in one call (to the `StringVar`'s `set()` method) instead of multiple ones in reverse order to `Listbox.delete()`.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not completely understand. Where and how should I use **listvariable=** and **StringVar**? Sorry, still a newbie here.

Comment: No problem. Tkinter is very poorly documented, IMO. Here's a tidbit of information I found about its various so-called [**Variable Classes**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and how they work (to some degree). Note: I don't think you need to use the `trace` functionality to do what you want, just `set()` and maybe `get()`.